# Jackson serialize a Map such that all elements are wrapped using their JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to configure Jackson to serialize a Map where each Object will then be wrapped by its FQDN.

For example:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>
map.put("object1", new a.b.c.D());
map.put("object2", new a.b.c.E());
```

Such that the output will become:

```
{
 "object1": {
   "a.b.c.D": {
     "x":"y"
    }
  },
  "object2": {
    "a.b.c.E": {
      "z":"a"
   }
 }
```

}

I believe I can achieve this by adding the following to all of the Pojo classes but can't seem to get the Map to serialize them.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

Comment: Sorry but, what is FQDN?

Comment: @Laazo I suppose it is FQCN which stands for Fully Qualified Class Name,